# Is NBG conservative over but not equiconsistent with ZFC in a constructive setting?

Tags: logic, set-theory

From what I know the simple argument about the equiconsistency of ZFC and NBG comes from the principle of explosion. That is, suppose NBG is inconsistent, then by explosion every formula in the language of NBG is provable which then by the property of being a conservative theory over the language of ZFC the latter would also be inconsistent. But then my questions are:

1. Is it true that in a constructive metatheory NBG is conservative over but not equiconistent with ZFC?
2. If the last question is true, are there any interesting consequences/theory development of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The simple argument about equiconsistency goes, roughly, by describing how a model of ZFC can be extended to a model of NBG. [See e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2603167/relation-between-consistency-of-zf-mk-and-nbg).]
2. This simple argument has nothing to do with explosion, and will still go though if you are officially working in your metatheory with e.g. Neil Tennant's classical Core Logic which lacks explosion.
3. You can be a constructivist (on a common understanding of what it takes to be a constructivist) and accept explosion. The canonical constructively acceptable logic is standard intuitionistic logic, which does have explosion.